# zend validation message not displaying

Tags: php, zend-framework

below code does not displaying the validation message, should i print any varable any where. please advise.

```
$username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username', array('autocomplete' => 'off'));
        $username->setLabel('Username')
                ->setDecorators($elementDecoration)
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->addFilter('StripTags')
                ->addFilter('StringTrim')
                ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true, array('messages'=>'Cannot be empty'));


$elementDecoration = array(

            'ViewHelper',
            'Description',
            'Errors',
            array(array('data'  => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),
            array('Label', array('tag' => 'td', 'placement' => 'prepend')),
            array(array('row'   => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr')),
        );
```

Comment: i be leave something is going wrong becauseof setDecorators

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$username->setLabel('Username')
                ->setDecorators($elementDecoration)
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->addErrorMessage('Cannot be empty')
                ->addFilter('StripTags')
                ->addFilter('StringTrim');
```

Make sure that the decorators used are correct.

```
$element->setDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'Description',
    'Errors',
    array(array('elementDiv' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div')),
    array(array('td' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),
    array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),
));
```

Comment: i just want to display validation message when the user is not entered, but currently it displaying the " Value is required and can't be empty "  message every field next. how to display validation message only when user is not entered.

Comment: plz check my setDecorators

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove the `setRequired` function from your element. This function is overriding the `NotEmpty` validator. Since you are checking for `NotEmpty`, you can remove `setRequired` in order to display your own message.